# Resolve IEnumerable of a generic in constructor with Autofac

Tags: c#, ienumerable, autofac, abstract-factory

So I have an abstract factory class, and the idea is that in the constructor of this factory, I will be passed from *autofac* an `IEnumerable` of all registered services I'm interested in.  There is a method in this factory that passes a parameter, and the code will loop through the `IEnumerable` and return the matching service.  Easy as pie, the abstract factory pattern.

The problem is, I've recently introduced a generic type in my interface the factory is returning, and I'm not sure how to write the constructor so *autofac* knows to still return all registered services, and ignore the generics essentially.

Some code:

My Interface:

```
public interface IRunnerServices<in T>
{
    void Create(T entity);
}
```

Some implementations of the interface

```
public class RunnerServiceA : IRunnerServices<A>
{
    public void Create(A entity);
}

public class RunnerServiceB : IRunnerServices<B>
{
    public void Create(B entity);
}

public class RunnerServiceC : IRunnerServices<C>
{
    public void Create(C entity);
}

// Many, many more...
```

And in my composition root, I register these services like this

```
builder.RegisterType<RunnerServicesA>().As<IRunnerServices<A>>();
builder.RegisterType<RunnerServicesB>().As<IRunnerServices<B>>();
builder.RegisterType<RunnerServicesC>().As<IRunnerServices<C>>();
```

And just so you know, A, B, C all inherit from the same base class

```
public class A : LetterBase
{ }

public class B : LetterBase
{ }

public class C : LetterBase
{ }
```

Now, my abstract factory

```
public class RunnerServicesFactory
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IRunnerServices<????>> _candidates;
    public RunnerServicesFactory(IEnumerable<IRunnerServices<????>> candidates)
    {
        _candidates = candidates;
    }

    public IRunnerServices<????> Create(int discriminator)
    {
        return _candidates.First(c => c.Discriminator == discriminator);
    }
}
```

The question lies in what do I provide above in the constructor and other declarations at ???? to let autofac know it should pass in all registered services of this generic?

I've tried this, but no luck as *autofac* passes nothing

```
IEnumerable<IRunnerServices<LetterBase>>
```

Comment: What you want is to use covariance and contravariance at the same time which is not possible. Do you need contravariance ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to cast your `RunnerServiceA` implementation to `IRunnerService<LetterBase>` you need to make `IRunnerService<T>` covariant with the out generic keyword modifier which is not possible because you have one method that accept a `T` argument.

.net won't allow you to cast `RunnerServiceA` to `IRunnerService<LetterBase>` you can try by doing this simple code :

```
var runnerService = (IRunnerServices<LetterBase>)new RunnerServiceA();
// Throws an InvalidCastException
```

One possible solution would be to make the `IRunnerService<T>` covariant like this :

```
public interface IRunnerServices<out T>
    where T : LetterBase
{
    void Create(LetterBase entity);
}
```

By doing this, you will be able to cast `RunnerServiceA` to `IRunnerService<LetterBase>` and doing this code :

```
IEnumerable<IRunnerServices<LetterBase>> runners = new IRunnerServices<LetterBase>[] {
                                                        new RunnerServiceA(),
                                                        new RunnerServiceB()
                                                    };
```

Then *Autofac* will be able to resolve `IEnumerable<IRunnerServices<LetterBase>>` if `RunnerService` is registered as `IRunnerServices<LetterBase>`

By the way what you are doing let me think about `IIndex<TKey, T>` :

```
public class RunnerServicesFactory
{
    private readonly IIndex<Char, IRunnerServices<LetterBase>> _candidates;
    public RunnerServicesFactory(IIndex<Char, IRunnerServices<LetterBase>> candidates)
    {
        _candidates = candidates;
    }

    public IRunnerServices<LetterBase> Create(Char discriminator)
    {
        return _candidates[discriminator];
    }
}
```

and the registration will be like this :

```
builder.RegisterType<RunnerServiceA>().Keyed<IRunnerServices<LetterBase>>('A');
builder.RegisterType<RunnerServiceB>().Keyed<IRunnerServices<LetterBase>>('B');
builder.RegisterType<RunnerServiceC>().Keyed<IRunnerServices<LetterBase>>('C');
```

Comment: I don't exactly understand your covarient solution, did you mistype something.  you declare IRunnerServices<out T>, but nowhere is there an output type of T.

Comment: @raterus the `out` modifier is present only to allow .net to cast `RunnerServiceA` to `IRunnerService<LetterBase>`.